# high bits of long multiplication in Java?

Tags: java, long-integer, multiplication

Is there any way to get the high half of the multiplication of two `long`s in Java? I.e. the part that vanishes due to overflow. (So the upper 64 bits of the 128-bit result)

I'm used to writing OpenCL code where the command `mul_hi` does exactly this: http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/mul_hi.html

Since OpenCL can do it efficiently on my CPU, Java should be able to do so as well, but I can't find how I should do this (or even mimic its behaviour efficiently) in Java. Is this possible in Java, and if so, how?

Comment: Do you mean the high 64 bits of the 128-bit result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The accepted solution is wrong most of the time (66%), though the error is bounded (it can be smaller than the exact result by at most 2 and it can never be bigger). This comes from

- ignoring the `x_lo * y_lo` product
- first shifting and then adding `x_hi * y_lo` and `x_lo * y_hi`

My solution seems to always work for non-negative operands.

```
final long x_hi = x >>> 32;
final long y_hi = y >>> 32;
final long x_lo = x & 0xFFFFFFFFL;
final long y_lo = y & 0xFFFFFFFFL;
long result = x_lo * y_lo;
result >>>= 32;

result += x_hi * y_lo + x_lo * y_hi;
result >>>= 32;
result += x_hi * y_hi;
```

Tested on a billion random operands. There should be a special test for corner cases and some analysis.

Dealing with negative operands would be more complicated as it'd prohibit using the unsigned shift and force us to handle intermediate result overflow.

In case speed doesn't matter much (and it rarely does), I'd go for

```
 BigInteger.valueOf(x).multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(y))
     .shiftRight(64).longValue();
```

Comment: You could link to or otherwise indicate the accepted solution in the future to avoid what happened now: your solution became the accepted one, so it isn't clear which solution you are referring to that is wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Java 9 has [Math.multiplyHigh](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#multiplyHigh-long-long-), which according to the Javadocs "Returns as a long the most significant 64 bits of the 128-bit product of two 64-bit factors."

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you have two longs, `x` and `y`, and `x = x_hi * 2^32 + x_lo`, and `y = y_hi * 2^32 + y_lo`.

Then `x * y == (x_hi * y_hi) * 2^64 + (x_hi * y_lo + x_lo * y_hi) * 2^32 + (x_lo * y_lo)`.

The high 64 bits of that product can, therefore, be computed as follows:

```
long x_hi = x >>> 32;
long y_hi = y >>> 32;
long x_lo = x & 0xFFFFFFFFL;
long y_lo = y & 0xFFFFFFFFL;
long prod_hi = (x_hi * y_hi) + ((x_ hi * y_lo) >>> 32) + ((x_lo * y_hi) >>> 32);
```

Comment: What would that yield for 0x1FFFFFFFF times 0x1FFFFFFFF?  By my reckoning, it would compute 1, but the correct answer should be 3.  I think to get a precise result, one must compute all four partial products and then sum them carefully.

Comment: @maaartinus: While I can see this to mimic lib/kernel/mul_hi.cl, "truncate each partial product, scale and sum" is still wrong - "scale and sum partial products, truncate" is right. It does not even get minimal expected error from skipping the least significant partial product for lack of rounding/"truncation precompensation". (Try decimal 19*19 for an example, if `0x1FFFFFFFF times 0x1FFFFFFFF` worked for you.) (2013/3/23: "Correct mul_hi()"? MA.)

Comment: @greybeard I know, I only fixed an error making it plain wrong. It's still slightly wrong most of the time, but it's not my answer, my answer is [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31629280/581205).

Answer (score 3):

If either x or y can be negative, you should use Hacker's Delight function (Henry S. Warren, Hacker's Delight, Addison-Wesley, 2nd edition, Fig. 8.2):

```java
long x_high = x >>> 32;
long x_low = x & 0xFFFFFFFFL;
long y_high = y >>> 32;
long y_low = y & 0xFFFFFFFFL;
long z2 = x_low * y_low;
long t = x_high * y_low + (z2 >>> 32);
long z1 = t & 0xFFFFFFFFL;
long z0 = t >>> 32;
z1 += x_low * y_high;
return x_high * y_high + z0 + (z1 >>> 32);
```

Comment: What is `y2`? How about providing a reference (page#, edition) or a hyperlink for _Hacker's Delight_?

Comment: I have added the fig. number and edition number, and I corrected my typo. As for the hyperlink, what do you have in mind? Amazon's page?

Comment: [Authoritative links](https://books.google.de/books?id=VicPJYM0I5QC&pg=PA174#v=onepage&q&f=false) not objectionable to many practitioners and legislations, preferably. Funny S. Warren should advise to _change parameters to 32-bit unsigned integers_, and continue to present the unchanged ed.1 16/32 bit code.

Comment: All ">>" should be replaced with ">>>" to use this method for unsigned multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code snippet from Java's `Math.multiplyHigh(long,long)`

```
    public static long multiplyHigh(long x, long y) {
        if (x < 0 || y < 0) {
            // Use technique from section 8-2 of Henry S. Warren, Jr.,
            // Hacker's Delight (2nd ed.) (Addison Wesley, 2013), 173-174.
            long x1 = x >> 32;
            long x2 = x & 0xFFFFFFFFL;
            long y1 = y >> 32;
            long y2 = y & 0xFFFFFFFFL;
            long z2 = x2 * y2;
            long t = x1 * y2 + (z2 >>> 32);
            long z1 = t & 0xFFFFFFFFL;
            long z0 = t >> 32;
            z1 += x2 * y1;
            return x1 * y1 + z0 + (z1 >> 32);
        } else {
            // Use Karatsuba technique with two base 2^32 digits.
            long x1 = x >>> 32;
            long y1 = y >>> 32;
            long x2 = x & 0xFFFFFFFFL;
            long y2 = y & 0xFFFFFFFFL;
            long A = x1 * y1;
            long B = x2 * y2;
            long C = (x1 + x2) * (y1 + y2);
            long K = C - A - B;
            return (((B >>> 32) + K) >>> 32) + A;
        }
    }
```

As from Java 9, this is included in java.lang.Math and probably direct call to it should be made. Posting the source just to show what is going on "under the hood".

Comment: This likely isn't what is going on under the hood. Hotspot will treat `multiplyHigh` as an intrinsic function on some platforms. That means that direct calls to this method can be replaced (by the JIT compiler) with code that takes advantage of native instructions that perform the same function. You could think of this code as a fallback option, which the JVM could use to emulate the instruction on architectures that don't have it.

Answer (score 1):

Some of described cases above works wrong. First of all you have to ask yourself what types of operands do you treat (signed/unsigned).

There is a modified code from sample above that is fixed for carry flag (treat x & y as unsigned 64-bit values):

```
public static long productHi(long x, long y) {
    final long x_hi = x >>> 32;
    final long y_hi = y >>> 32;
    final long x_lo = x & 0xFFFFFFFFL;
    final long y_lo = y & 0xFFFFFFFFL;
    long result = (x_lo * y_lo) >>> 32;
    long a = x_hi * y_lo;
    long b = x_lo * y_hi;
    long sum = a + b + result;
    long carry = ((a & b) | (~sum & (a ^ b))) >>> 63;
    result = (sum >>> 32) + x_hi * y_hi + (carry << 32);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look at using a [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).