# How can I handle 128 bit little endian multiplication in Java without resorting to BigInteger

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, 64-bit, biginteger, multiplication

I need to multiply two 8 byte (64 bit) arrays in the fastest way possible. The byte arrays are little endian. The arrays can be wrapped in a ByteBuffer and treated as little endian to easily resolve a java "long" value that correctly represents the bytes (but not the real nominal value since java longs are 2s compliment).

Java's standard way to handle large math is BigInteger. But that implementation is slow and unnecessary since im very strictly working with 64 bits x 64 bits. In addition, you can't throw the "long" value into one because the nominal value is incorrect, and I can't use the byte array directly because it's little endian. I need to be able to do this without having to use up more memory / CPU to reverse the array. This type of multiplication should be able to execute 1m+ times per second. BigInteger doesn't really come close to meeting that requirement anyway, so I'm trying to do it via splitting the high order bits from the low order bits, but I can't get it working consistently.

The high-order-bits-only code is only working for a subset of longs because even the intermediate addition can overflow. I got my current code from this answer....

[high bits of long multiplication in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18859207/high-bits-of-long-multiplication-in-java)

Is there a more generic pattern for getting hi/lo order bits from 128 bit multiplication? That works for the largest long values?

Edit:

FWIW I'm prepared for the answer to be.. "cant do that in java, do it in c++ and call via JNI". Though I'm hoping someone can give a java solution before it comes to that.

Comment: Find a math library that handles that in an optimized fashion?

Comment: Have you played with the [unsigned utility methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseUnsignedLong-java.lang.String-)?

Comment: I wonder what your use case is that makes the built in 64 bit long multiplication is inadequate.

Comment: I've looked for a library, but couldnt find one. Everyone says use BigInteger, but im not multiplying 1000 digit numbers, so it's too much overhead.

I have looked at the unisigned utility methods, but they only add overhead by converting to strings, which is unnecessary.

Here is my use case:  -1501598000831384712l x -735932670715772870l;

Comment: are you sure you can't simply multiply the 2 longs together?  https://www.javamex.com/java_equivalents/unsigned_arithmetic.shtml  "unsigned addition, subtraction and multiplication are identical: we can just use the ordinary +, - and * operators;"

Comment: It doesnt have anything to do with the sign really. It's the overflow that's the problem. Regardless of the sign,  the result of the above operation overflows the 64 bits that a long can use. The sign is only a problem when trying to move it into a BigInteger, because a big integer respects the 2's compliment (signed) value. Keep in mind, the above use case is still *unsigned*. It's just the representation that's signed. If you move that string into a BigInteger it will then become *signed*, which is incorrect.

Comment: You can easily turn longs into BigIntegers in an unsigned way though

Comment: Can you explain? The unsigned bits of -1501598000831384712 will not fit into a java long.

Comment: They do, because they're the same bits, just with a different interpretation. All you need to do is to perform the conversion in an unsigned way. For example, add `BigInteger.valueOf(2).pow(64)` if the input is negative.

Comment: No, they do not fit. You cannot represent the *exact* bits of that literal in a way that that java interprets as positive long. It will always be negatively signed.  So show me how I would get the bits of -1501598000831384712 into a BigInteger correctly (without converting to a byte array, which defeats the entire purpose, per my original post)

Comment: Bits are just bits. Java calling the long negative doesn't mean the bits aren't there. But all of that is just leading to using BigInteger, which you said you didn't want to do, so you can use one of the other "high bits of multiplication" techniques.

Comment: Sorry man, but if you put those two negative numbers directly into BigIntegers and multiply them, you get 1105075027093306281540683661382363440, which is not the correct answer. As I said before, BigInteger does not respect the unsigned bit representation. It interprets it as a literal value.

Comment: Yea that's why I said "add [stuff] if the input is negative". That fixes the interpretation.

Comment: I agree that will work, but I guess IMO that didn't exactly fit the description of "easily turn longs into BigIntegers". It requires an extra unnecessary operation. The solution below is more what I was looking for. Last step is to check the performance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Java 9 (which was a bit too new at the time this question was asked), there is now a trivial way to get the upper half of the 128-bit product of two *signed* 64-bit integers: [`Math.multiplyHigh`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#multiplyHigh-long-long-)

There is a relatively simple conversion from "upper half of signed product" to "upper half unsigned product" (see Hacker's Delight chapter 8), which can be used to implement an unsigned multiply high like this:

```
static long multiplyHighUnsigned(long x, long y) {
    long signedUpperHalf = Math.multiplyHigh(x, y);
    return signedUpperHalf + ((x >> 63) & y) + ((y >> 63) & x);
}
```

This has the potential to be more efficient (on platforms on which `multiplyHigh` is treated as an intrinsic function by the JIT) than the more manual approach used by the old answer, which I will leave below the line.

---

It can be done manually without BigInteger by splitting the longs up into two halves, creating the partial products, and then summing them up. Naturally the low half of the sum can be left out.

The partial products overlap, like this:

```
  LL
 LH
 HL
HH
```

So the high halves of LH and HL must be added to the high result, and furthermore the low halves of LH and HL together with the high half of LL may carry into the bits of the high half of the result. The low half of LL is not used.

So something like this (only slightly tested):

```
static long hmul(long x, long y) {
    long m32 = 0xffffffffL;
    // split
    long xl = x & m32;
    long xh = x >>> 32;
    long yl = y & m32;
    long yh = y >>> 32;
    // partial products
    long t00 = xl * yl;
    long t01 = xh * yl;
    long t10 = xl * yh;
    long t11 = xh * yh;
    // resolve sum and carries
    // high halves of t10 and t01 overlap with the low half of t11
    t11 += (t10 >>> 32) + (t01 >>> 32);
    // the sum of the low halves of t10 + t01 plus
    // the high half of t00 may carry into the high half of the result
    long tc = (t10 & m32) + (t01 & m32) + (t00 >>> 32);
    t11 += tc >>> 32;
    return t11;
}
```

This of course treats the input as *unsigned*, which does not mean they have to be positive in the sense that Java would treat them as positive, you can absolutely input -1501598000831384712L and -735932670715772870L and the [right answer](https://ideone.com/JlMJva) comes out, as confirmed by [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0xeb294092f5023378%20*%200xf5c971229761c03a).

If you are prepared to interface with native code, in C++ with MSVC you could use [__umulh](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67xf5cy5.aspx), and with GCC/Clang you can make the product as an `__uint128_t` and just shift it right, the codegen for that is [actually fine](https://godbolt.org/g/AfdtJr), it doesn't cause a full 128x128 multiply.

Comment: Excellent. This is what I was looking for, the other code just had some flaws in the addition that caused overflows. Thanks!

Comment: FWIW the performance of this should be a lot worse than if you did the same thing with native code. Native code can do it in just one multiplication instead of 4 plus a bunch of filler. A JNI call does have overhead of course, so hopefully you can move an entire loop to the native side.

Comment: Gotcha.  That may end up happening, but at least for future reference I'll understand the most performant way to do it in Java!

Comment: @DanWatson: `the other code just had some flaws in the addition that caused overflows` if you can edit or comment that *other code* easily enough, by all means do so.

Comment: @greybeard it's possible to add the scaled upper half of `t00` to `t01` (or `t10`) but I could not find a way to do it that actually helps - though I did not benchmark it and perhaps the slightly different structure matters in practice.

Comment: expect result as 128 bit number, else suggest "return x*y"