# Emulating multiplication of 128-bit integers with pairs of 64-bit integers

Tags: java, java-me

I'm implementing Pollard's rho algorithm in J2ME, but the number I want to factorise is a `long` already and I need to be able to square the input number and subsequent 128-bit numbers produced. Seeing as this is J2ME and I have no access to `BigInteger` how can I calculate the result of these multiplication as a high and a low `long` in software.

Comment: Solution in C, in case you know how to convert from that: [How can I multiply 64 bit operands and get 128 bit result portably?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25096197/5221149)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [high bits of long multiplication in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18859207/5221149)

Comment: See also: [How can I handle 128 bit little endian multiplication in Java without resorting to BigInteger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47941995/5221149)

Comment: @Andreas This isn't a duplicate of that, since I want to be able to multiply two emulated 128-bit integers together wheras in the linked question they're attempting to multiply two 64-bit integers to produce a 128-bit integer

Comment: The first answer of the duplink directly answers your question.  Split your 128 bit number into 2 64 bit numbers ...