# What is the fastest way to computer remainder/modulo of primitive number types in Java?

Tags: java, performance, bit-manipulation, modulo

I as trying to port

```cpp
(uint64_t)(((__uint128_t)word * (__uint128_t)p) >> 64);
```

given [here](https://github.com/lemire/fastrange/blob/master/fastrange.h) (described [here](https://lemire.me/blog/2016/06/27/a-fast-alternative-to-the-modulo-reduction/) and [here](https://github.com/lemire/fastrange)) to Java. Since Java does not have 128 bit type and using `BigInteger` will not make it faster than `word % p`, what is the fastest way to implement modulo/remainder which can run faster than the built in `%` operator in Java primitive numeric types including longs?

Comment: Maybe I am just uninformed but I would have expected that the Java Compiler does this job for me. I mean when it is faster and produces the same results why the Java Compiler should not always generate optimized code?

Comment: It seams like that the C/C++ compilers are not doing this optimisation. I am not sure if Java does it either.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [high bits of long multiplication in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18859207/high-bits-of-long-multiplication-in-java) (by the way the trick described there by D. Lemire is not a remainder, it is *a different way* to do range-reduction which avoids taking a remainder - actually it's a fixedpoint scaling)

Comment: @FabianBarney it does not produce the same results, it produces results that are "equally useful" in the context of eg hashmaps, but not the *same* result so compilers cannot just do this replacement. It's not actually a way to compute the remainder, but it solves the bigger picture problem of reducing the range of a random integer (any value) into the range [0..p)

Comment: @harold Thanks for clarification. I have to say that the question is a bit misleading then.