# efficient way to compute the overflow bits after multiplication

Tags: algorithm, optimization

This is a conceptual question about an algorithm which is related to a problem I'm personally solving.

It's common in real-life CPU architectures to store the overflow bits in a certain register after multiplication, but what if this feature is not available? Is there an efficient way to compute the overflow bits?

Since it's an *overflow* `a * b >> bits` is not an option.

Comment: Take a look at normalising ("floating point") multiplication: You *can* trade almost half of the computations inevitable for an exact result if accepting notable inaccuracy. (Did a "23 bit ± 5 LSB multiply" on a [Motorola 68000](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorola_68000) back in the day.)

Comment: "Any useful CPU architecture stores the overflow bits in a certain register after multiplication." This is a rather strong statement. There are many useful CPU architectures which do not have an N x N -> 2N multiply. PowerPC, Alpha AXP, AArch64 for example. Or are you saying that the Power Mac and your Android phone are not useful?

Comment: @RaymondChen I changed my statement in case I missed something, but don't the RISC-style CPUs have a separate instruction to compute the overflow bits?

Comment: @xiver77 Yes, but there is no "multiply and give me the both the result and the overflow" which is what your text suggests. You can keep the result and discard the overflow, or keep the overflow and discard the result. It is unclear which of the processors, if any, fuse the instructions into a single multiply.

Comment: (See also: [high bits of product?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18859207) & linked/related.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can imagine two basic options.

1. Old CPUs did not support multiplication at all. We had to do it manually. You can always implement multiplication by addition and shifting. This algorithm is quite simple and not limited to any number of bits (because both addition and shifting is easy to do in any number of bits on all CPUs).
2. If your CPU can do multiplication without overflow in N bits, you can use this as a helper to get the result faster than bit-by-bit computation mentioned above. If a and b are N-bit wide each, then the result of a * b is 2N wide. If you split a and b to halves, then each half is N/2 wide, their product is N-bit wide. So you multiply halves with each other and then add them together. If we mark upper half a2/b2 and lower half a1/b1, then lower result is a1 * b1, middle result is a2 * b1 + a1 * b2, upper result is a2 * b2, each time plus overflow. I hope it is trivial enough so detailed description is not necessary.

Comment: So assuming two 32-bit numbers, this is what you're explaining right? `a * b = (a2 * 2^16 + a1) * (b2 * 2^16 + b1) = a2 * b2 * 2^32 + (a2 * b1 + a1 * b2) * 2^16 + a1 * b1`. Your answer helped!